# How do I update columns of a Room entity only if it's null?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database, android-architecture-components

Is there a way to update columns of an entity **only if** the columns are null? Here's my Update function in my DAO interface:

```
@Query("UPDATE media SET media_name = :mediaName, media_data = :mediaData WHERE id = :id")
fun update(id: Int, mediaName: String?, mediaData: String?)
```

... because as of now, a value of "null" is updated for these columns.

Comment: Do you mean `UPDATE media SET media_name = :mediaName, media_data = :mediaData WHERE id = :id AND media_name IS NULL AND media_data IS NULL`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry for not being clear, but pretty much with non-null params only being updated to the database, so like `@Query("UPDATE media SET media_name = :mediaName, media_data = :mediaData WHERE id = :id AND :mediaName IS NOT NULL AND :mediaData IS NOT NULL")` except that this doesn't work

Comment: Um, just check for `null` on those values before calling `update()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, that's what I thought, but was wondering if there was a more ideal SQL alternative for this. Thanks Mark :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
@Query("UPDATE media SET media_name = (CASE WHEN media_name IS NULL THEN :mediaName ELSE media_name END), media_data = (CASE WHEN media_data IS NULL THEN :mediaData ELSE media_data END) WHERE id = :id")
fun update(id: Int, mediaName: String?, mediaData: String?)
```